# Jquery and PhP: Adding Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-animate

I am creating a a random number generator that has a big blue button, that you click. As soon as you click it, I use jquery and ajax to submit the form without refreshing the page. I get a random number between 0 and 100. What I do is that I replace the value of the button with the number that was generated. Here is the code that I have...

```
$('form.roll').on('submit', function() {
var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};
that.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.va();
    data[name] = value;                 
});

$.ajax ({
    url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $(function() {
                $("#roll").val(response);
            });
        }
});
console.log(data);
return false;
});
```

and here is the button

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="roll" value="Roll Dice">
```

Now this seems to work, but it does not look good. I would like to animate it. What I want to do is that is kind of flashes in, stays for a few seconds, and then slowly fades away back to "roll dice", like the animation here: (just click on superuser and change it, you will see the animation.
http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html

What i want is that if it is less that 50, the flash is green, and when it rolls more that 50 its red. The number that is displayed is something like "29.67". Two digit number, with two decimals.

I would also like to add loading gif while the php function is being processed.

I hope this makes sense, and that you can help me out. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) provides a **Highlight effect** which probably matches your need: http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/. Color is customizable.

Usage is:

```
$("#number").effect('highlight', { color: 'red' });
```

I made up a fiddle for your scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/QG7hE/1/

Comment: I have tried to implement it in my code by doing this inside the function http://pastie.org/8363179 and it wont seem to work. I have jquery ui installed, and dont know what to do :( Also if you didnt know, i submit the form to php, which generates the number and then sends it back to the page as a response, which i display.

Comment: It seems fine to me. Do you have any error in browser's console?

Comment: I am not trying to replace the button, but replace the value from roll dice to the number, with a few animations... I will check again and let you know if there are server errors...

Comment: Actually instead of doing that, can you please just help me make it so that when it is generating the number and what not in php, then button displays a loading circle from here? http://www.ajaxload.info/ Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do i put this ($("#number").html("<img src='http://www.ajaxload.info/cache/FF/FF/FF/00/00/00/1-0.gif' />");) in the huge chuck of code above? Thanks!

Comment: Before the call to `$.ajax`, I assume

Comment: where exactly? Thanks! Sorry I am being such a n00b :)